# Guidance needed to create better query in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a table containing data as shown below
[image]

I have created this query to return the result

```
SELECT id,customer_name,job_number, 
IF(designer_name='des1',total_hrs, "") as des1,
IF(designer_name='des2',total_hrs, "") as des2,
IF(designer_name='des3',total_hrs, "") as des3,
IF(designer_name='des4',total_hrs, "") as des4 

FROM practice.test;
```

[image]

If there are 50 designers that would mean I will have to write the If statement multiple times which would not be good.

I want to know if there is a better way to get the result?

Table Code:

```
--
-- Database: `practice`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `designer_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `job_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `total_hrs` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `designer_id`, `designer_name`, `customer_name`, `job_number`, `total_hrs`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'des1', 'aa', 'j101', '11'),
(2, 1, 'des1', 'bb', 'j102', '8'),
(3, 2, 'des2', 'cc', 'j103', '2'),
(4, 2, 'des2', 'dd', 'j104', '2'),
(5, 2, 'des2', 'ee', 'j105', '5'),
(6, 3, 'des3', 'ff', 'j106', '13'),
(7, 3, 'des3', 'gg', 'j107', '32'),
(8, 3, 'des3', 'ii', 'j108', '4'),
(9, 3, 'des3', 'kk', 'j109', '3'),
(10, 3, 'des3', 'll', 'j110', '4'),
(11, 4, 'des4', 'mm', 'j111', '1'),
(12, 4, 'des4', 'nn', 'j112', '6');
```

Comment: It is a Pivot table problem; Consider handling Data display related requirements in your application code (eg: PHP, C++ etc).

Answer (score 0):

What is that you're trying to achieve? If it's the total of hours try with

```
SELECT designer_name, sum(total_hrs) FROM test GROUP BY designer_id
```

Comment: I am trying to generate a pivot table using the query I mentioned in the post. The problem is the if statement 

    IF(designer_name='des1',total_hrs, "") as des1,

I have the write the designer_name='desX' for each value for designer_name. I want to know if there is any better way to achieve the result. If the number of the designers increase I will have to manually edit the query and add in the new line for the new designer.

Comment: Do the query that I wrote gave you the information you're looking for? If so, please don't forget to mark any response as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It's have no sense. I don't think what you really need this.
What the problem to do simple request like

```
SELECT id, customer_name, job_number, designer_name, total_hrs
FROM practice.test
```

Can you explain, why you need result in this way. Probably, you have wrong logic in code, what will handle result.